# call a javascript function from radiobutton which is inside a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Here is my gridview.

```
  <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvQuestion"
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <input type="radio" runat="server" name="optionAS" value="1" id="optionAS_1"  onclick='disableAs(this,<%# Eval("QuestionId") %>,1)' />

    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code inside onclick causing error. How can i fix it.

Comment: in server side controls need to use onclientclick event instead of click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have following code instead:

```
onclick='<%# String.Format("disableAs(this,{0},1);",Eval("QuestionId"))%> '
```